# can I configure a nano mouse receiver?

Tags: arch-linux, usb, mouse

I'm sure lot of us lost the usb nano receiver (let's call it UNR because the name is long), y'know that small thing that comes with the wireless mouse, because these things happen. For me I lost 1 mouse and the UNR is still on my laptop then I bought another one, same brand another model and it doesn't work.

So I was wondering if *I can code a config file or access the usb nano receiver to configure it for another different mouse*.

And, more important

*Why the heck they don't do a wireless universal controller?*
Maybe each brand, don't do a universal driver because that makes it exclusive? correct me if I'm wrong I can't imagine why.

Comment: We don't even a universal wireless frequency.  That's why we have 802.11n/b/g.  Contrary to ethernet cabling (which had decades of data from phone cabling, not that ethernet turned out great but for other reasons) IEEE did not make a firm grip on 802.11 standardization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the nano-receiver with a different (but compatible) mouse, you'll need to use a tool such as [Solaar](http://pwr.github.io/Solaar/) ([which is packaged for Arch](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/solaar)) to pair your new mouse with the receiver.

As to your second question, there is a universal protocol, Bluetooth HID; but Bluetooth mice are more expensive than mice using proprietary protocols.